# Terraform error when using dynamic block in for_each

Tags: terraform0.12+

I was trying to upgrade terraform to V0.12, and try to use for_each and dynamic block to implement more flexible resources. but there are some errors.
main.tf

```
resource "azurerm_eventhub" "entities" {
  for_each = var.eventhub_ns_name
  namespace_name      = each.value.ns_name
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  dynamic "eh_name_associations"{
    for_each = each.value.event_hub
    content {
      name = eh_name_associations.value.eh_name
      partition_count     = eh_name_associations.value.partition_count
      message_retention   = eh_name_associations.value.message_retention
    }
  }
}
```

vars.tf

```
variable "eventhub_ns_name" {
  type = map(object({
    ns_name    = string,
    event_hub  = list(object({
      eh_name  = string
      partition_count = number
      message_retention = number
    })),
  }))
  
  default ={
   eventhub_ns_name001={
    ns_name = "eventhub001",
    event_hub = [{
      eh_name = "survey"
      partition_count = 1
      message_retention = 1
    },
    {
      eh_name = "wechat"
      partition_count = 2
      message_retention = 1
    }],
    },
  }
}
```

The errors:
The argument "partition_count" is required, but no definition was found.
The argument "message_retention" is required, but no definition was found.
The argument "name" is required, but no definition was found.
Blocks of type "eh_name_associations" are not expected here.

Comment: Yes, terraform is correct, what is `eh_name_associations` supposed to be, that does not exist in the provider. You need to create multiple instances of `azurerm_eventhub` instead of dynamic `eh_name_associations` within it, because that simply is not supported.

Comment: thanks for your answer, and it ended up a workaround.  But I'm still wondering when to use dynamic block,  and from lots of docs, is it like a sub for expressions in for expressions?

Comment: You can use dynamic block if and only if the resource you are trying to deploy has configuration within nested blocks. `azurerm_eventhub` does not. An `azurerm_application_gateway` for example does.